# Prevent the site from running a javascript code from the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I did an experiment with the php function `htmlspecialchars()` with an input from the browser. It works and the value echoed from the database does not run the script. However if I do input the script directly into the database meaning in phpMyAdmin, the codes:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['fname'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');?>
```

And

```
<?php echo  htmlspecialchars($row['lname']);?>
```

Still runs the javascript I put directly into the database on the browser. Does it have to do with the database collation type or something else?

Comment: Why have you tagged `javascript` to your question if your question has no relation to the language? I would suggest you remove it before you find your question being down voted or closed.

Comment: Are you storing that PHP in your DB?

Comment: No, it's a sample code in the php file. I tried inserting a direct js script in the database which still worked even with htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript (from PHP/MySQL perspective) is just a string like any other string.

You need to know when/what/how to ***filter***, and when/what/how to ***escape***.

**Filter**: Is filtering out malicious strings *before* inserting it into database. Like the function `strip_tags()`

**Escape**: Is escaping characters (like `"`, `'`, `<`, `>`, etc) *before* printing out result that may give you undesired output. Like the function `htmlspecialchars()`

---

#### Warning

Storing JavaScript in DB then outputting it into browser is easy, but also dangerous! Make sure only admin users are allowed to do that.

Comment: So ideally, before posting a data I have to use `$variable = strip_tags($_POST['variable']); then use `htmlspecialchars()` on echo?

I'll have to check the code again, htmlspecialchars() still doesn't prevent the script from running on this ` <?php echo  htmlspecialchars($row['lname']);?>`

Comment: @Deer-san Simply right-click > view page source, and see what's the output of that. If you want to print out JavaScript code in HTML as readable text for users, then you need to simply replace `<` with `&lt;` and replace `>` with `&gt;`. Replacing these characters is actually done by `htmlspecialchars()`